# Ajax form submit after validating input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form which collects some information using text boxes. Some text boxes have a strick pattern, e.g. few input boxes take only numbers.

I was able to add validation using pattern attribute of input field. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

However, when user submits the form I need to do a ajax post request to a different end point. So, I think I have to make a call to preventDefault() method to prevent default form submit.

But when I call preventDefault(), it also disables validating input fields.

How can I achieve validating fields and make a ajax request, only if the input fields pass the validation.

Comment: You can just call a javascript function and have `onsubmit="return false"` on your form. You would also want the submit button to call your js function `<button class="submit" onclick="awesomeFunction()">Submit</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can either way use this:

First change the `input[type="submit"]` to this:

```
<button onclick="submitThis()">Save</button>

function submitThis() { 
  var firstInput = $("#idoffirstinput).val(); // basic validation
  if(firstInput == "correctinput") {
     $.ajax({
       // send the ajax form
     })
  }
}
```

You can seperately validate each input using the technique provided there, or the one I provided. The jQuery error will be same; I mean the validation.

Use this:

```
if(firstInput == "correctinput") {
  // ajax form
} else {
  // show the error popup!
}
```

The plus point for this one is that you can style the error dialouge popup too. Like

```
$("#errordiv").css("border", "1px solid #hexcode");
```

And everything else is same!

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML and jQuery:
<form id="details">
    Phone no: <input type="text" id="phone_no" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>

var input   = $('#phone_no').val();
if(input != '')
{
    var YOUR_URL = 'www.example.com';
    var formData = $('#details').serialize();// If you want to pass that data to that   URL
    $.post(YOUR_URL,formData,function(result){

    });
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```